# UVM-SystemC library 'make check' error

Tags: c++, makefile, uvm, systemc

I'm getting following error in `make check` inside objdir of uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha1 library.

```
../configure
make 
make install
```

commands works fine. Also, I've SystemC-2.3.1 installed and it works fine. Detailed log from `make check` [makecheck.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnU5P-lglPDdTZKQXBrMjlVYjg/view?usp=sharing)

```
  CXXLD  simple/callbacks/basic/test
../../src/uvmsc/.libs/libuvm-systemc.so: undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_time::to_string[abi:cxx11]() const'
../../src/uvmsc/.libs/libuvm-systemc.so: undefined reference to `sc_dt::convert_to_fmt(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, sc_dt::sc_numrep, bool)'
../../src/uvmsc/.libs/libuvm-systemc.so: undefined reference to `sc_dt::sc_uint_base::to_string[abi:cxx11](sc_dt::sc_numrep, bool) const'
../../src/uvmsc/.libs/libuvm-systemc.so: undefined reference to `sc_dt::sc_uint_base::to_string[abi:cxx11](sc_dt::sc_numrep) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1064: recipe for target 'simple/callbacks/basic/test' failed
make[3]: *** [simple/callbacks/basic/test] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mayur/DV/SystemC/uvm-systemc-1.0/objdir/examples/uvmsc'
Makefile:1637: recipe for target 'check-am' failed
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mayur/DV/SystemC/uvm-systemc-1.0/objdir/examples/uvmsc'
Makefile:310: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mayur/DV/SystemC/uvm-systemc-1.0/objdir/examples'
Makefile:341: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the linker is unable to find SystemC related variables. This may be because the path to your SystemC-2.3.1 is not available to the uvm-systemc-1.0-alpha scripts which are invoking the check related test cases.

Re-run the `configure` with the SystemC-2.3.1 path in your system.

```
../configure --with-systemc=/path/to/your/systemc-2.3.1
e.g.
../configure --with-systemc=/home/mayur/DV/SystemC/SystemC-2.3.1
```

File `INSTALL` in your uvm-systemc-1.0/ contains the required instructions.

Once you rerun the scripts ensure that in the `objdir/Makefile` the variables below are set to your SystemC-2.3.1 library path.

```
SYSTEMC_CFLAGS = -I<your path>/systemc-2.3.1/include
SYSTEMC_LIBS = -L<your path>/systemc-2.3.1/lib -lsystemc
```

Comment: I've also tried running wit --with-systemc option. And objdir/Makefile has those variables set properly. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: can you put up the full/detailed log file. Also does the systemC-2.3.1 check files run and pass , is the library present in the <your path>/systemc-2.3.1/lib/libsystemc.so

Comment: Yes. Its present in <path>/systemc-2.3.1/lib-linux64/libsystemc-2.3.1.so Output from configure command [configure.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnU5P-lglPDdm1KQ2ZsX0pvZU0/view?usp=sharing). And SystemC library with examples works just fine.

Comment: as the -l options is -lsystemc the library file name should be libsystemc.so . There should be at least a link libsystemc.so which would be pointing to libsystemc-2.3.1.so .

Comment: Reinstalled SystemC libraries. Now libsystemc.so file is there in <path>/systemc-2.3.1/lib-linux64/libsystemc-2.3.1.so. Thanks a lot for the help.